# Optimize update user profile fields using query

Tags: mysql, joomla, query-optimization, inner-join

Attempting to update some user profile fields in Joomla from an imported users table that has table look ups for particular fields. Looking for some speed improvements as my user database is large and the following query times out...

```
    CREATE TABLE joomla.updated_users(UserID varchar(255),Active varchar(255),Absent varchar(255),AllowReconcile varchar(255),Prefix varchar(255),FirstName varchar(255),MiddleName varchar(255),LastName varchar(255),Suffix varchar(255),Email varchar(255),PhoneWork varchar(255),PhoneHome varchar(255),PhoneMobile varchar(255),Fax varchar(255),CountryCode varchar(255),AddressLine1 varchar(255),AddressLine2 varchar(255),MailStop varchar(255),City varchar(255),State varchar(255),PostalCode varchar(255),RequiredApprovals varchar(255),DivisionId varchar(255),OrganizationID varchar(255),LocationID varchar(255),PositionID varchar(255),CostCenterID varchar(255),PartnerType varchar(255),PartnerStatus varchar(255),TrendSegment varchar(255),MonthofService varchar(255),Status varchar(255),Classification varchar(255),LastHireDate varchar(255),OriginalHireDate varchar(255),ApproverID varchar(255),ManagerID varchar(255),Ethnicity varchar(255),Username varchar(255)) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

    CREATE TABLE joomla.updated_organisation(ID varchar(255),Title varchar(255),ParentID varchar(255),Active varchar(255)) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;

    UPDATE joomla.user_profiles
    INNER JOIN joomla.users ON joomla.users.id = joomla.user_profiles.user_id AND joomla.user_profiles.profile_key = 'organisation'
    INNER JOIN joomla.updated_users ON joomla.updated_users.Email = joomla.users.email
    INNER JOIN joomla.updated_organisation ON joomla.updated_users.OrganizationID = joomla.updated_organisation.ID
    SET joomla.user_profiles.profile_value = joomla.updated_organisation.Title;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For the core profile plugin? Are you data in one row per user?  Do you have profile fields that you are not updating? And you are matching the users based on email address?

Comment: Are running the query during a Joomla page render or as sql script directly against DB?

Comment: Running it as a SQL script direectly against the DB. The data is in one row per user (updated_users table) however, it contains columns with IDs such as "organizationID" that references a third table.